# GameplayKit: NPC element is going to very high floating number coordinates and back on update

Tags: swift, macos

I have plugged in my GKBehavior/GKAgent2D/GKComponent system for some behavioral routines and am having trouble fixing this bug I can't figure out.
   Let me first be descriptive:
   My current Entity/Component system is based on apple's ECS where:
1-entitymanager:GKEntity manages all components and contains all entities in the game and uses updateWithDelta which goes into all GKComponentSystems which themselves update every component within their system.
Currently, the update order is as follows:
behavior> node> playerNode> sound> interface> physics
2-Each system is a GKComponentSystem which handles updating all elements within.
I have two extensions of NSViewController called GameRenderer and GameControls which both are delegates of SCNSceneRendererDelegate and a custom protocol called KBAndTouchDelegate which update render on screen and control respectively (will be changing this to be incorporated in the ECS once my order updates feel right).
Now, in the behavior componentSystem, it updates a MoveComponent which contains a few functions for updating (willUpdate and didUpdate). Both have a 2DAgent position that is first taken from an SCNNode's position (converted from SCNVector3 to Float2 with just x and z coordinates being changed) then reflected back onto the node after the behavioral algorithm is evaluated.
Here are snippets for the updates:

```
    func agentWillUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
        guard let nodeComponent = entity?.componentForClass(SCNNodeComponent.self)
            else{
                return
        }
        let nodePos = nodeComponent.node.position
        position = float2(Float(nodePos.x), Float(nodePos.z))

    }

    func agentDidUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
        guard let nodeComponent = entity?.componentForClass(SCNNodeComponent.self)
            else{
                return
        }
        let pos = SCNVector3(x: CGFloat(position.x), y: nodeComponent.node.position.y, z: CGFloat(position.y))
        print("\(nodeComponent.node.name) changed to \(pos)")
        nodeComponent.node.position = pos
    }
```

The @override updateWithDeltaTime routine checks for the party in which the moveComponent's owner is and placed in an array for getting the closest enemy distance and return the enemy. 
   The behavior has very low maxSpeed and maxVelocity factors.
   Running the application, I printed a set of movements for two nodes which are enemies and monitor each other's position. The enemy search routine works fine as they reflect each other’s position in alternate sequence. The result is below:

```
Optional("zombie") changed to SCNVector3(x: -20.0, y: 0.0, z: -20.0)
enemy position is: (0.0, 0.0)
Optional("player") changed to SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
enemy position is: (-20.0, -20.0)
Optional("zombie") changed to SCNVector3(x: -20.0, y: 0.0, z: 41567.44140625)
enemy position is: (0.0, 0.0)
Optional("player") changed to SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
enemy position is: (-20.0, 41567.44140625)
HRTF loaded
Optional("zombie") changed to SCNVector3(x: 30.136764526367188, y: 0.0, z: -20.2421875)
enemy position is: (0.0, 0.0)
Optional("player") changed to SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
enemy position is: (30.1367645263672, -20.2421875)
Optional("zombie") changed to SCNVector3(x: -38636.87109375, y: 0.0, z: 15289.939453125)
```

If looking at the first positions of the "zombie" you will see it starts at -20, -20 then goes to impossibly big values for both x and z positions (again, x and z in the scene's world). The player doesn't move as I don't use any controls just to see if the zombie is able to find the player with the following GKBehavior call

```
    init(targetSpeed: Float, seek: GKAgent, avoid: [GKAgent]){
        super.init()

        if targetSpeed>0{
            setWeight(0.1, forGoal: GKGoal(toReachTargetSpeed: targetSpeed))
setWeight(0.5, forGoal: GKGoal(toSeekAgent: seek))
setWeight(1.0, forGoal: GKGoal(toAvoidAgents: avoid, maxPredictionTime: 1.0))
    }
    }
```

The above behavior is called in MoveComponent for the zombie's enemy (the player). Meaning the zombie will seek for the player.
   Can anyone tell me what the hell these ginormous values for x and z are ? The zombie and player are about sqrt(800) or 28 meters away. But the zombie goes to stuff like 35800 meters away on x then switches back to about 50 then back and forth at each frame.
There’s a definite pattern and I’m not sure whether this GKBehavior uses A star at which point the probabilistic roadmap sets some very odd coordinate samples but nowhere in my code is there any scalar that would move the zombie so far away and flip the distances back to something reasonably normal every frame.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be having the same issue, as of yesterday 21-03-2016, the issue has been resolved by apple with their newest public update of x-code 7.3.